# struggle trying create new series

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following df :

```
                A   C
Date        
2015-06-29   196.0  1
2015-09-18   255.0  2
2015-08-24   236.0  3
2014-11-20    39.0  4
 2014-10-02    4.0  5
```

How can I generate a new series that is the sum of all the previous rows of column c ?

This would be the desired output:

```
D

1 
  #This second row of value 3 is the sum of first and second row of column c
3
 #This third row of value 6 is the sum of first, second and third row 
  value of column c , and so on
6
10
15
```

I have tried a loop such as:

```
for j in range (len(df)):
new_series.iloc[j]+=df['C'].iloc[j]
return new_series
```

But does not seem to work

Comment: You want [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html#pandas.Series.cumsum)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC you can use [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html#pandas.Series.cumsum) to perform this:

```
In [373]:    
df['C'].cumsum()

Out[373]:
Date
2015-06-29     1
2015-09-18     3
2015-08-24     6
2014-11-20    10
2014-10-02    15
Name: C, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @EdChum

Answer (score 1):

Numpy alternatives:

```
In [207]: np.add.accumulate(df['C'])
Out[207]:
2015-06-29     1
2015-09-18     3
2015-08-24     6
2014-11-20    10
2014-10-02    15
Name: C, dtype: int64

In [208]: np.cumsum(df['C'])
Out[208]:
2015-06-29     1
2015-09-18     3
2015-08-24     6
2014-11-20    10
2014-10-02    15
Name: C, dtype: int64

In [209]: df['C'].values.cumsum()
Out[209]: array([ 1,  3,  6, 10, 15], dtype=int64)
```